# Network Issue on Ubuntu 16 Server

Tags: 16.04, networking

Can't' figure out what someone did to this freshly installed server, but please see attached. Ubuntu 16.

The /etc/network/interfaces is still exactly how I set it up. So I'm a bit confused. Rebooting server didn't fix it either. The server has a full /24 C class subnet routed to it.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlm1C.png)

[interfaces file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHmm6.png)

Comment: Well, `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument` suggests there is an error in the interface configuration

Comment: @steeldriver what file would I check? I set this up for someone else remotely.

Comment: @steeldriver updated OP to add interfaces screenshot. Please check.

Comment: What do you have in /etc/network/interfaces.d/? Do you have resolvconf installed? And blanking out portions of the addresses does nothing for security, it just makes it harder for us to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @heynnema there's nothing in /etc/network/interfaces.d/. Yes I blanked out the first 2 octets of the IP for the client's security and privacy. Nothing wrong with that. The issue is not that. The IP addresses are set correctly by me and were working perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have resolvconf installed?

Comment: @heynnema I see /etc/resolvconf directory with these files/dirs inside: interface-order, resolv.conf.d, update.d, update-libc.d.